# Remove Default Title from Chart (HighChart)

Tags: json, highcharts, label, tooltip, title

I wanted to remove a title that appears on Highchart when I leave the mouse on the graph. I already tried to remove the title and it still appears.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yH9lj.png)

I've tried using Title inside the chart and outside and nothing happens. Put the text = '' and it doesn't work either.

Example:

```
{
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        marginBottom: 40,
        title: {enabled: false},
    },    
    xAxis:{
        labels:{
            style:{
                color: 'black',
                fontSize:'11px'            
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Please can you give an example on jsfiddle please?

Answer (score 0):

The title options object should not be defined inside the chart options.

See: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ayjw6pom/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, ...]
    }]
});
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/title.text

If this wouldn't help please reproduce your issue on some online editor which I could work on.